# how to hide the context of a text field and show it when click button

Tags: android, eclipse, button, keyboard

***how do i hide the context of the text field and show it when i click 
the button 
i do not want to hide the whole text filed just the context i wrote inside it
and show ot when i click a button 
**** 
this is a small code*

```
  package com.example.nonachan;

    import android.R.string;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    char a;
    char b;
    char c; 
    int i = 0; 
    char buf;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final EditText t =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);  
                 ImageButton n = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b1);            
                n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        a = 'a';
                       t.setText(t.getText().toString() + a);   
                    //   t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }       

                });

                ImageButton a = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b2);
                a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                         b = 'b' ;
                         t.setText(t.getText().toString() + b);

                        // t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         i++; 

                    }
                });

                ImageButton m = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b4);
                m.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                         c = 'c' ;
                         t.setText(t.getText().toString() + c);

                         //t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         i++; 

                    }
                });

                Button l = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
                l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                    //  t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: please don't post your whole code, instead post the relevant pieces and also your code is very inconsistently indented

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have misspelled contents as context in your question (looks very likely)

instead of trying to hide the contents of the `EditText`, just save it to a variable and set the text of the `EditText` to empty. Then in your button click just set the text back to the contents in your local variable

Eg

```
String hiddenText = null;

EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);

ImageButton hide = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b1); 
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // save and hide
        hiddenText = text.getText();
        text.setText("");
    }       
});

ImageButton unhide = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.b2); 
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // unhide the text and 'clear' hiddenText
        if (hiddenText != null) {
            text.setText(hiddenText);
            hiddenText = null;
        }
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it. It depends how you want to do it. These are just some suggestions off the top of my head, you can even use them all together.

You can put any entered text in a separate string and then if invisible set the TextView to show an empty string, if visible set the TextView to the saved string.

You can use the visibility tag.

You can set the text color to the background color.

You can create/remove the TextView on visible/invisible states.

You can replace the text with symbols for secure inputs if you want (for each character in edittext display an asterisk or something) and then change that back to plain text.

There are a hundred and one ways of doing it, if you search around on previously answered questions you will see several different methods.